# To filter multiple columns with a condition on the results

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to find a way of highlighting a result with multiple conditions. I have no knowledge of pivot tables. I would rather use a formula or macros. The table is organised by Dealer.

Acc      NAME   Add       Dealer  Total
68687    Sara    11 Wood   111A   0
68687    Sara    11 Wood   111A   0
32187    Sara    11 Wood   111A   0
12345    Tom    10 Main    7878C   2
12345    Tom    10 Main    7878C   2
54321    Tom    10 Main    7878C   2

My table is similar to the one above. I want to select where the Total is greater than 0 & for each Dealer each unique Account number with the lowest Account number highlighted somehow.

So the results I want for the table above would be: Dealer 7878C, Accounts **12345**, 54321.

12345 being the lower of the two, it is highlighted.

I don't mind copying the results onto another sheet, as I don't want to remove any data from the sheet. I started by just filtering the Totals for >0 and I was thinking of trying to filter for unique values in Account but its the next step that I am stuck on. A countifs formula?

The sheet is quite large and I'm just not sure which is the best way to try and do it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you could add a helper column and do a countif and then filter on that helper column

Comment: how did you get your table in?  did you cut and paste it from somewhere?  it came in nicely formatted.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used html to format the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a nice but complicated way to do it.

With your original data:
[image: Sheet view original data]
With changed data:
[image: Sheet view edited data]

As you can see I've placed your data in `A1:E7`.
I use two array formulas, one for the Dealer in `G2:G5` and one for the Accounts `H2:N5`. The Dealer formula is vertical, and the Accounts formula is horizontal.

For the dealers put this **array formula** in `G2` (press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to enter it):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$7,SMALL(IF(($E$2:$E$7>0)*(COUNTIF($G$1:$G1,$D$2:$D$7)=0),ROW($D$2:$D$7)-1),ROW($G$1:$G1))),"")
```

Now copy `G2` down to `G3:G5` to get the rest of the relevant dealers.

For the accounts put this **array formula** in `H2`:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(($D$2:$D$7=$G2)*(COUNTIF($G2:G2,$A$2:$A$7)=0),$A$2:$A$7),1),"")
```

Now copy `H2` to the right, `I2:N2`, and down to `H3:N5`.

To make the first accounts bold I simply make the `H` column formatted as **Bold**.

You can copy these formulas farther as needed. Note that the locations are important. If you want to place the formulas elsewhere you'll need to change the references accordingly.

### Formulas explained

What these formulas do is check for your conditions, and then get the smallest value that hasn't been retrieved yet, in the upper / left most cells.

The two formulas are mostly the same, apart from the fact that in the account numbers we can use the actual numbers, and with the dealer we use the row number instead.

The dealer formula from the inside out:

1. The conditions are set in the `IF` part of the formula, with a multiplier `*` as a logical `AND` (`TRUE*TRUE=TRUE FALSE*TRUE=FALSE`).
2. The first condition in `IF(($E$2:$E$7>0)*(COUNTIF($G$1:$G1,$D$2:$D$7)=0),...` checks for the row's Total value to be greater than zero, the second condition checks that the dealer is not already present in the `G` column. The second condition is irrelevant in the first cell, but in the second cell `G3` it becomes `COUNTIF($G$1:$G2,...` which returns more than 0 if the dealer already exists, and evaluate to `FALSE`.
3. If the conditions are met the `IF` returns the dealer's index by using its row minus 1 `ROW($D$2:$D$7)-1`, which returns 1 for the first etc. as the starting row is 2. Otherwise it returns `FALSE` which is ignored.
4. The `SMALL` function returns the k-th smallest item. It ignores the `FALSE` items, and in our case returns the k-th smallest index that meets the conditions (Total>0 and not already present in the results). `SMALL(...,ROW($G$1:$G1)` in the first cell return the first item. `ROW($G$1:$G2)` in the second cell `G3` evaluates to 2 and returns the second smallest item, and so forth.
5. The `INDEX` function simply returns the dealer from the data according to the index.
6. And finally, the `IFERROR` is there only to hide the errors when the end of the results is reached.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am having difficulty trying to change the range in your formula. I don't know how long the sheet will be so I have:  

Dim LastRow As Long, 
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row     

- to get the length. I then try to edit your formula as:            

=IFERROR(INDEX(R2C4:R" &LastRow& "C4,SMALL(IF((R2C5:R" &LastRow& "C5>0)  etc. 

but I keep getting an error message. Is this the right way to try this?

Comment: You are mixing up a few things here, and some won't work this way. A better way would be to make a Named Range for the data (Formulas>Name Manager) and use that name in the formula. The range can be changed there manually, or have it be dynamically calculated like `=OFFSET(A2:A200,0,0,COUNTA(A2:A200))` for the range of Accounts.

Answer (score 0):

based on your sample data and assuming a header row in row 1 and the left column being column A.

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)
```

place that in F2 and copy down.  Then do a filter on the helper column =1